# Store multiple ratings in a single table row

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

How to store multiple ratings without repetition of the row against which the ratings are stored

```
create table pic_table
(user_id varchar2(10) not null,
 pic_id number not null,
 pic_snap bfile,
 rating number,
 constraint snp_pk primary key (pic_id));

insert into pic_table
values(u1,p1, bfilename('GIF_FILES', 'PIC_1'),'JPEG');
```

User1 uploads a picture and it can be rated 1,2, or 3. Then user2 rates the pic as 2 and u3 rates the pic 3. Are 3 columns required to log each rating, and do I need 3 rows to log each user rating for the picture, i.e.

```
user_id pic_id  vote_1  vote_2   vote_3
u1      pic_1           u2       u3
```

What if there are more than 2 users ratings, i.e. if user4 rates 2 and user5 rates 3. How to store this data and calculate an aggregate?

```
user_id pic_id    v_1   v_2 v_3
u1          pic_1       u2  u3
u1          pic_1       u4  u5
```

This will take enormous space. Can i use a record to store the values in the form of an array and calculate an aggregate by extracting the results out of the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table 'ratings' with the following fields:

```
user_id (int)
pic_id (int)
rating (int)
```

I'd advise making the user_id and pic_id a combined primary key.

Do all your calculations on this table and you should have no troubles with space..

Comment: Thank you.                                                              Still this table needs to hold the different ratings given by users for a pic_id, i.e. if 10 users rate one picture then it means 10 rows! The columns will just be user_id,pic_id,rating (u1,p1,1;u2,p1,2;u3,p1,3;u4,p1,1). If 20 pictures are rated then it means 200 rows to store the ratings, isn't there an efficient solution?

Comment: True, but as this table consists of only integers it won't be a problem with filesize. Rewriting this using storing arrays or adding multiple columns will increasy complexity, add more overhead and be less dynamic in the long run.

Comment: Perhaps other users can offer alternatives, but in my opinion this is the best solution!

Comment: Oli, Thank you very much. Greatly appreciate your help. If other users can suggest any alternatives to store multiple ratings more efficiently, please share.

Comment: If you are really tight on storage then you can make the rating a char(1) which may take less space than a int, depending on how your RDBMS stores the data. Consult your database tuning manual.